# Identity involving difference of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I am trying to prove the following identity but not sure how to prove it.

[The followings are equivalent forms of the original equality I asked.]
$$
\binom{m+n}{s+1} - \binom{n}{s+1} = \sum_{i=0}^s \frac{m}{s-i+1}\binom{m+1+2(s-i)}{s-i}\binom{n-2(s-i+1)}{i}.
$$
$$
{m+n\choose s+1} - {n\choose s+1}
= \sum_{q=0}^s \frac{m}{q+1} 
{m+1+2q\choose q} {n-2-2q\choose s-q}
$$
$$
\binom{m+n}{s} = \sum_{i=0}^{s} \frac{m}{m+2i}
\binom{m+2i}{i}\binom{n-2i}{s-i}
$$

[Please ignore my attempt. It only explains one of equivalent forms.]

My attempt is to use the combinatorial argument.
The lefthand side could be understood as follow. 
Suppose we have a box containing $m$ black balls and $n$ white balls.
We randomly draw $s+1$ balls out of it.
Then the LHS represents the number of ways that the selected $s+1$ balls.

However, not sure how to make a combinatorial argument on the RHS.
Based on the RHS, the sum of all cases of drawing $s-i$ balls from somewhere and $i$ balls from white balls.
But it is unclear to me to show the above identity.

Any suggestions/answers would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Then the LHS represents the number of ways that the selected s+1 balls."  I don't understand this.  Is something missing from this sentence?

Comment: You have posted several different identities, replacing the previous one every time. It may be useful to make a list.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thank you so much. I made changes. I thought no one is working on this. I do really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remark.** What follows answers one  of several queries that appeared
at this post, which each query replacing the previous one. We  suggest
making a list so that all the different varieties may be examined.

Starting from the claim

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{m+n\choose s+1} - {n\choose s+1}
= \sum_{q=0}^s \frac{m}{q+1} 
{m+1+2q\choose q} {n-2-2q\choose s-q}}$$

we observe that

$${m+1+2q\choose q+1} - {m+1+2q\choose q}
\\ = \frac{m+1+q}{q+1} {m+1+2q\choose q} - {m+1+2q\choose q}
\\ = \frac{m}{q+1} {m+1+2q\choose q}.$$

Therefore we have two sums,

$$\sum_{q=0}^s
{m+1+2q\choose q+1} {n-2-2q\choose s-q}
- \sum_{q=0}^s
{m+1+2q\choose q} {n-2-2q\choose s-q}.$$

For the first one we write

$$\sum_{q=0}^s
[w^{q+1}] (1+w)^{m+1+2q} [z^{s-q}] (1+z)^{n-2-2q}
\\ = \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; 
 (1+w)^{m+1} [z^s] (1+z)^{n-2}
\sum_{q=0}^s \frac{1}{w^{q+2}} z^q (1+w)^{2q} (1+z)^{-2q}.$$

We  may extend  $q$ beyond  $s$ because  of the  coefficient extractor
$[z^s]$ in front, getting

$$\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^2} (1+w)^{m+1} [z^s] (1+z)^{n-2}
\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q w^{-q} (1+w)^{2q} (1+z)^{-2q}
\\ =\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; (1+w)^{m+1} [z^s] (1+z)^{n-2}
\frac{1}{w^2} \frac{1}{1-z(1+w)^2/w/(1+z)^2}
\\ =\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; (1+w)^{m+1} [z^s] (1+z)^{n}
\frac{1}{w} \frac{1}{w(1+z)^2-z(1+w)^2}.$$

Repeat the calculation for the second one to get

$$\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;  (1+w)^{m+1} [z^s] (1+z)^{n}
\frac{1}{w(1+z)^2-z(1+w)^2}.$$

Now we have

$$\left(\frac{1}{w}-1\right)\frac{1}{w(1+z)^2-z(1+w)^2}
= \frac{1}{w-z} \frac{1}{w(1+w)}
- \frac{1}{1-wz} \frac{1}{1+w}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z/w} \frac{1}{w^2(1+w)}
- \frac{1}{1-wz} \frac{1}{1+w}.$$

We thus obtain two components, the first is

$$\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;  (1+w)^{m+1} [z^s] (1+z)^{n}
\frac{1}{1-z/w} \frac{1}{w^2(1+w)}
\\ = \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^2} (1+w)^{m} 
[z^s] (1+z)^{n} \frac{1}{1-z/w} 
\\ = \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^2} (1+w)^{m} 
\sum_{q=0}^s {n\choose q} \frac{1}{w^{s-q}}
= \sum_{q=0}^s {n\choose q}
\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{s-q+2}} (1+w)^{m} 
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^s {n\choose q} [w^{s-q+1}] (1+w)^m
= [w^{s+1}] (1+w)^m \sum_{q=0}^s {n\choose q} w^q
\\ = - {n\choose s+1} 
+ [w^{s+1}] (1+w)^m \sum_{q=0}^{s+1} {n\choose q} w^q.$$

We may  extend $q$ beyond  $s+1$ due  to the coefficient  extractor in
front, to get

$$- {n\choose s+1} 
+ [w^{s+1}] (1+w)^m \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q} w^q
= - {n\choose s+1} 
+ [w^{s+1}] (1+w)^{m+n}$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{m+n\choose s+1} - {n\choose s+1}.}$$

We have the claim, so we just  need to prove that the second component
will produce zero. We obtain

$$\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;  (1+w)^{m+1} [z^s] (1+z)^{n}
\frac{1}{1-wz} \frac{1}{1+w}
\\ =\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; (1+w)^{m} [z^s] (1+z)^{n}
\frac{1}{1-wz} 
\\ =\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; (1+w)^{m} 
\sum_{q=0}^s {n\choose q} w^{s-q}
= \sum_{q=0}^s {n\choose q} \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; w^{s-q}  (1+w)^{m} 
= 0.$$

This concludes the argument.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detailed explanation? Not sure where $\sum_{q=0}^s
[w^{q+1}] (1+w)^{m+1+2q} [z^{s-q}] (1+z)^{n-2-2q}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} 
 (1+w)^{m+1} [z^s] (1+z)^{n-2}
\sum_{q=0}^s \frac{1}{w^{q+2}} z^q (1+w)^{2q} (1+z)^{-2q}$ comes from.

Comment: I must refer you to *Computation of combinatorial sums* by G. P. Egorychev.

Comment: Thanks! I will read it

Comment: And I would like to say thank you for your instructive answer. Your answer widens my perspective of combinatorics!

Answer (score 3):

This is a mere supplement to @MarkoRiedel's instructive answer slightly streamlining a few steps.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{q=0}^s}&\color{blue}{\frac{m}{q+1}\binom{m+1+2q}{q}\binom{n-2-2q}{s-q}}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^\infty\left(\binom{m+1+2q}{q+1}-\binom{m+1+2q}{q}\right)\binom{n-2-2q}{s-q}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^\infty\left([w^{q+1}]-[w^q]\right)(1+w)^{m+1+2q}[z^{s-q}](1+z)^{n-2-2q}\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([w^1]-[w^0]\right)(1+w)^{w+1}[z^s](1+z)^{n-2}\sum_{q=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(1+w)^2}{w}\right)^q\left(\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}\right)^q\tag{3}\\
> &=[w^0z^s]\left(\frac{1}{w}-1\right)(1+w)^{m+1}(1+z)^{n-2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{(1+w)^2z}{w(1+z)^2}}\tag{4}\\
> &=[w^0z^s](1-w)(1+w)^{m+1}(1+z)^n\frac{1}{w(1+z)^2-(1+w)^2z}\\
> &=[w^0z^s](1-w)(1+w)^{m+1}(1+z)^n\frac{1}{w\left(1-\frac{z}{w}\right)(1-wz)}\\
> &=[w^0z^s](1-w)(1+w)^{m+1}(1+z)^n\left(\frac{1}{w\left(1-w^2\right)\left(1-\frac{z}{w}\right)}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.-\frac{w}{\left(1-w^2\right)(1-wz)}\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=[w^0z^s](1+w)^{m}(1+z)^n\left(\frac{1}{w\left(1-\frac{z}{w}\right)}-\frac{w}{1-wz}\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=[w^1z^s](1+w)^{m}(1+z)^n\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{w}}\\
> &=[w^1](1+w)^m\sum_{j=0}^s\binom{n}{j}[z^{s-j}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^k\tag{7}\\
> &=[w^1](1+w)^m\sum_{j=0}^s\binom{n}{j}\frac{1}{w^{s-j}}\tag{8}\\
> &=[w^{s+1}](1+w)^m\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{n}{j}w^j-\sum_{j=s+1}^\infty\binom{n}{j}w^j\right)\\
> &=[w^{s+1}](1+w)^m\left((1+w)^n-\sum_{j=s+1}^\infty\binom{n}{j}w^j\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{m+n}{s+1}-\binom{n}{s+1}}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.
>
> The essential steps are (1) where we get rid of the denominator by using a representation as *difference* of binomial coefficients and the partial fraction decomposition in (5).

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\frac{m}{q+1}\binom{m+1+2q}{q}=\binom{m+1+2q}{q+1}-\binom{m+1+2q}{q}$.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (4) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* and apply again the rule from (3).
- In (5) we do a partial fraction expansion.
- In (6) we observe the right term $\frac{w}{1-wz}=w+w^2z+w^3z^2+\cdots$ can be skipped, since there is no contribution to $[w^0]$.
- In (7) we do again a geometric series expansion and expand the binomial.
- In (8) we select the coefficient of $z^{s-j}$.
- In (9) we select the coefficient of $w^{s+1}$.

> **OPs first identity:**
>
> The right-hand side of the first identity follows from the right-hand side of the second by reversing the order of summation $q\to s-q$.
>
> **OPs third identity:**
>
> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^s}&\color{blue}{\frac{m}{m+2j}\binom{m+2j}{j}\binom{n-2j}{s-j}}\\
> &=\binom{n}{s}+\sum_{j=1}^s\frac{m}{m+2j}\binom{m+2j}{j}\binom{n-2j}{s-j}\tag{10}\\
> &=\binom{n}{s}+\sum_{j=1}^s\frac{m}{j}\binom{m+2j-1}{j-1}\binom{n-2j}{s-j}\tag{11}\\
> &=\binom{n}{s}+\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\frac{m}{j+1}\binom{m+1+2j}{j}\binom{n-2-2j}{s-1-j}\tag{12}\\
> &=\binom{n}{s}+\binom{m+n}{s}-\binom{n}{s}\tag{13}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{m+n}{s}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (10) we separate the first summand with $j=0$.
- In (11) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (12) we shift the index and start with $j=0$.
- In (13) we apply (9) by substituting $s$ with $s-1$.

Comment: This is very nice work. I was going to do the re-write myself and then I thought you might want to contribute here. We now have a complete page. Upvoted.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for your nice comment. It's always a pleasure to learn from your posts.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice work. In (4), how do we know the geometric series converges? Are we assuming $|(1+w)^2/w| < |(1+z)^2/z|$?

Comment: In equation (7), it seems that it needs to be $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^k$.

Comment: @induction601: You're welcome. We work with *formal* power series and do not consider any convergence issues. Thanks for the hint, typo corrected.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: You might want to add an answer to *[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049876)* to enhance the variety of different approaches.