# Conjecture $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}^22^{-4n} \frac{n(6n-1)}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)}=\frac{2C}{\pi} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, catalans-constant

I was observing this interesting [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03221)

and conjecture this result,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{2n \choose n}^2}{2^{4n+1}} \frac{n(6n-1)}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)}=\frac{C}{\pi} \tag1 \label1$$

Where [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) is Catalan's constant $=0.9156965...$

I am unable to present a prove of \eqref{1}.

How do we go about to prove its?

Comment: Mathematica agrees with your conjecture, and it gives the answer very quickly, suggesting there is a reasonably straightforward derivation. I can’t suggest how to prove it myself. A similar sum is mentioned here, with some suggested approaches. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3054440/60500

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Answer Without Legendre Polynomials and Elliptic Integrals**

Using the integral
$$
\frac1\pi\int_0^1\frac{x^n\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\tag1
$$
and the sum
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}r^n=\frac1{\sqrt{1-r}}\tag2
$$
we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}r^k
=\frac1\pi\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-rx}\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\tag3
$$
Substituting $r\mapsto r^2$ in $(3)$ and integrating in $r$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac{r^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
&=\frac1\pi\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin\left(r\sqrt{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{1-x}}\\
&=\frac2\pi\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin(rx)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Plugging in $r=1$, and using the result from $(11)$, yields
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac1{2k+1}}
&=\frac2\pi\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
&=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=\color{#C00}{\frac{4\mathrm{G}}\pi}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathrm{G}$ is [Catalan's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Substituting $r\mapsto r^2$ in $(3)$, dividing by $r^2$, and integrating in $r$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac{r^{2k-1}}{2k-1}
=\frac1{\pi r}\int_0^1\frac{-\sqrt{1-r^2x}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\tag6
$$
Plugging in $r=1$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#090}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac1{2k-1}}
&=\frac1\pi\int_0^1\frac{-1\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}\\
&=\color{#090}{-\frac2\pi}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Dividing $(6)$ by $r$, and integrating in $r$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac{r^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)^2}
&=\frac1{\pi r}\int_0^1\frac{\left(r\sqrt{x}\arcsin\left(r\sqrt{x}\right)+\sqrt{1-r^2x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\\
&=\frac2{\pi r}\int_0^1\frac{\left(rx\arcsin(rx)+\sqrt{1-r^2x^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Plugging in $r=1$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#00F}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac1{(2k-1)^2}}
&=\frac2\pi\int_0^1\frac{\left(x\arcsin(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
&=\frac2\pi\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}x\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+1\right)\\[6pt]
&=\color{#00F}{\frac4\pi}\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{2^{4k+1}} \frac{k(6k-1)}{(2k-1)^2(2k+1)}
&=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\left(\color{#C00}{\frac{1/2}{2k+1}}\color{#090}{+\frac1{2k-1}}\color{#00F}{+\frac{1/2}{(2k-1)^2}}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\color{#C00}{\frac{2\mathrm{G}}\pi}\color{#090}{-\frac2\pi}\color{#00F}{+\frac2\pi}\right)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\mathrm{G}}\pi}\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Result used in $\boldsymbol{(5)}$:**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2i\int_0^{\pi/2}x\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-i(2k+1)x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{-2}{2k+1}\int_0^{\pi/2}x\,\mathrm{d}e^{-i(2k+1)x}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{-2}{2k+1}\left(\frac\pi2(-i)(-1)^k-\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-i(2k+1)x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=i\frac{\pi^2}4+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2i}{(2k+1)^2}\left((-i)(-1)^k-1\right)\\
&=i\frac{\pi^2}4+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}-i\frac{\pi^2}4\\[6pt]
&=2\mathrm{G}\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 17):

Fourier-Legendre series provide a very simple derivation. We may recall that
$$ K(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right]^2 x^n $$
$$ E(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right]^2 \frac{x^n}{1-2n} $$
hence, by partial fraction decomposition and reindexing, the computation of the given series boils down to the computation of the integrals

$$ I_1 = \int_{0}^{1}K(x^2)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx $$
$$ I_2 = \int_{0}^{1}E(x)\,dx \qquad I_3=\int_{0}^{1}K(x)\,dx.$$
All of them are straightforward, since
$$ K(x)\stackrel{L^2(0,1)}{=}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2}{2n+1}P_n(2x-1) $$
$$ E(x)\stackrel{L^2(0,1)}{=}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{4}{(1-2n)(2n+1)(2n+3)}P_n(2x-1) $$
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\stackrel{L^2(0,1)}{=}\sum_{n\geq 0} 2(-1)^n P_n(2x-1)$$
hence
$$ I_1 = 2C,\qquad I_2 = \frac{4}{3},\qquad I_3 = 2.$$

This technique has been extensively used in our (Campbell's, Sondow's and mine) joint work [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03221).

Comment: Jack, your work and contribution to this site are truly remarkable.

Comment: @Klangen: I'm flattered :)