# Concerning this sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n+1}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}{2n \choose n}\right]^2=\frac{\Gamma^4\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{16\pi^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was looking at this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.08411.pdf) and saw this nice sum in section [12] of the paper,

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n+1}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}{2n \choose n}\right]^2=\frac{\Gamma^4\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{16\pi^2}\tag1$$

out of curiosity I conjectured the following two sums

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)^2}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}{2n \choose n}\right]^2&=\frac{4\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\tag2\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n^2}{(2n-1)^2}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}{2n \choose n}\right]^2&=-\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{8\pi\sqrt{2\pi}}\tag3
\end{align*}$$

I am unable to prove them.

**How do we go about to prove these two sums?**

Comment: What made you conjecture them?

Comment: I suppose that,as in the linked paper, we would need to use hypergeometric functions first summing from $0$ to $p$.

Comment: +1 for link to the nice paper. May be Jack D'Aurizio can shed some light on your conjectured identities.

Comment: All the given series can be written in terms of the moments of $K(x)$ or $E(x)$, i.e. $\int_{0}^{1}x^\eta K(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1}x^\eta E(x)\,dx$. Since the complete elliptic integrals have simple Fourier-Legendre expansions, these identities can be proved through harmonic analysis, too. That's the whole point of the paper in a nutshell ;)

Comment: This question is currently in the "Close" review queue.  I am voting to keep it open, as I think that the link to the paper provides sufficient context to motivate the question.  I am leaving this comment here as a message to future reviewers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the beautiful [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057181/348034) by @robjohn, we learn
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac{r^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)^2}
=\frac2{\pi r}\int_0^1\frac{\left(rx\arcsin(rx)+\sqrt{1-r^2x^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{equation} 
Plugging in $r=i$,
\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-1)^2}
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1\frac{\left(ix\arcsin(ix)+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\sinh^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1\left[ \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}B\left( \frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2} \right)\\
&=\frac{4\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma^2\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}
\end{align} 
(the integration of the $\sinh^{-1}$ term was made by parts).

For the second expression, we decompose
\begin{equation}
 \frac{n^2}{\left( 2n-1 \right)^2}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\left( 2n-1 \right)^2}
\end{equation} 
From the linked answer we have also
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac{r^{2k-1}}{2k-1}
=\frac1{\pi r}\int_0^1\frac{-\sqrt{1-r^2x}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
\end{equation} 
and thus, with $r=i$
\begin{align}
  \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}
&=-\frac1{\pi }\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\\
&=-\frac2{\pi }\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi}E\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\\
&=-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\left[ \frac{\Gamma^2\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}{8\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma^2\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}\right]
\end{align} 
where the [singular value $k_1$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValuek1.html) for the elliptic integral is used. We may also express from the answer
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}r^{2k}
=\frac1\pi\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-r^2x}\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
\end{equation} 
which, with $r=i$ again, gives
\begin{align}
  \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}^2}{16^k}(-1)^{k}
&=\frac1\pi\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\\
&=\frac2\pi\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}B\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \right)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2\Gamma^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn^2}{(2n-1)^2}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}{2n \choose n}\right]^2\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{8\Gamma^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\left[ \frac{\Gamma^2\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}{8\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma^2\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}\right]+\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma^2\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}
\end{align}
Using the reflection formula $\Gamma(3/4)\Gamma(1/4)=\pi\sqrt{2}$, we obtain finally
\begin{equation}
 S=-\frac{\Gamma^2\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)}{8\sqrt2\pi^{3/2}} 
\end{equation} 
as expected.

**Edit** (simpler derivation for the second expression)

For the second expression, it is easier to leave the integrals unevaluated in the decomposition:
\begin{equation}
 S=\int_0^1\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}}+\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} \right]\,dx
\end{equation} 
or
\begin{align}
 S&=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\\
 &=-\frac{1}{8\pi}\int_0^1 \left( 1-u \right)^{-1/2}u^{-3/4}\,du\\
 &=-\frac{B\left( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2} \right)}{8\pi}
\end{align}
and the result follows from the $\Gamma$ reflection formula.