# Is there an identity between the Clausen function $\rm{Cl}_8\left(\frac\pi3\right)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^9\,\binom {2n}n}$?

Tags: definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, special-functions, zeta-functions, experimental-mathematics

Given the log sine integral,

$$\rm{Ls}_m\Big(\frac{\pi}3\Big) = \int_0^{\pi/3}\Big(\ln\big(2\sin\tfrac{\theta}{2}\big)\Big)^{m-1}\,d\theta$$

we have in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213038/on-binomial-sums-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nk-binom-2nn-and-log-sine-in),

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac\pi{2!}\,\rm{Ls}_2\Big(\frac{\pi}3\Big) &=-\frac34\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3\,\binom {2n}n} -\zeta(3)\\
\frac{2^3\pi}{3!}\rm{Ls}_4\Big(\frac{\pi}3\Big) &=-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5\,\binom {2n}n} -19\zeta(5)-2\zeta(2)\zeta(3) \\
\frac{2^8\pi}{5!}\rm{Ls}_6\Big(\frac{\pi}3\Big) &=-24 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^7\,\binom {2n}n} -493\zeta(7)-48\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-164\zeta(3)\zeta(4) \\
\frac{2^{10}\cdot9\pi}{7!}\rm{Ls}_8\Big(\frac{\pi}3\Big) &=-6^3 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^9\,\binom {2n}n}-13921\zeta(9)-6^4\zeta(2)\zeta(7)-6087\zeta(3)\zeta(6)\\ &-4428\zeta(4)\zeta(5)-192\zeta^3(3)\end{aligned}$$

while in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3209547/4781),

$$\begin{aligned}
\rm{Ls}_2\Big(\frac\pi3\Big) &= -\rm{Cl}_2\Big(\frac\pi3\Big)\\
\rm{Ls}_4\Big(\frac\pi3\Big) &= -\tfrac92\rm{Cl}_4\Big(\frac\pi3\Big)-\tfrac12\pi\,\zeta(3)\\
\rm{Ls}_6\Big(\frac\pi3\Big) &= -\tfrac{135}2\rm{Cl}_6\Big(\frac\pi3\Big)-\tfrac{35}{36}\pi^3\,\zeta(3)-\tfrac{15}{2}\pi\,\zeta(5)
\end{aligned}$$

with the *Clausen function* for ***even*** $m$,

$$\rm{Cl}_m(x) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^m}$$

These identities imply a ***triple relation*** between $\rm{Ls}_m\big(\frac\pi3\big)$, $\rm{Cl}_m\big(\frac\pi3\big)$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{m+1}\,\binom {2n}n}$

> **Q:** However, the triple relation for $m=8$ is missing. Is there also for $m=8$?

Comment: Yes, I already tried. Either Mathematica gave me the wrong digits (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254436/a-bug-in-wolfram-alpha-about-an-infinite-series)), or I used the wrong zeta constants, or there really is no triple relation for $m=8$.

Comment: You want a relation between $\text{Ls}_8(\pi/3)$ and $\text{Cl}_8(\pi/3)$?

Comment: @FDP: A relation between any of the three: $$\rm{Ls}_8\big(\frac\pi3\big),\;\rm{Cl}_8\big(\frac\pi3\big),\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^9\,\binom {2n}n}$$ that is not in the list above will be quite nice to add.

Comment: Using GP PARI: clau(x)={imag(polylog(8,exp(I*x)))}
logsin(s)={intnum(x=0,s,log(2*sin(x/2))^7)}
lindep([clau(Pi/3),logsin(Pi/3),Pi*zeta(7),Pi^3*zeta(5),Pi^5*zeta(3)]) no relation found.

Comment: @FDP: Thanks, I already tried with an old version of Mathematica, but there's always the uncertainty that my version may not be giving the correct digits.

Comment: $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^8 \binom{2 n}{n}}=-4 \pi  \text{Gl}\left(\{6,1\},\frac{\pi }{3}\right)+36 \text{Gl}\left(\{7,1\},\frac{\pi }{3}\right)+\frac{\pi ^2 \zeta (3)^2}{9}+4 \zeta (5) \zeta (3)-\frac{266677 \pi ^8}{440899200}$$ Here $\text{Gl}$ denotes level six Multiple Zeta Values. It is highly likely that these MZVs are irreducible.