# Finding a closed form for the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^3}{64^n(n+1)^k}$ for $k=1,2,3,4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals, catalan-numbers

**Context:**

This question is related to [Calculate $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{C_n^2}{16^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753179/calculate-sum-n-0-infty-fracc-n216n/4753252) and [Is there a closed form for a give infinite sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253424/is-there-a-closed-form-for-a-give-infinite-sum/4753259#4753259).
We have also:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^3}{64^n(n+1)^2}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^4}{2\pi^3}-\frac{96\pi}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^4},\tag{1}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^3}{64^n(n+1)^3}=8-\frac{384\pi}{\Gamma{(\frac{1}{4})}^4}\tag{2}.$$
Both can be obtained in an elementary way (avoiding hypergeometric functions).
I have derived:
$$I=-\frac{32}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{(k)}\sin^2{(x)}}dxdk\\=4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^3}{64^n(n+1)}-\frac{2\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^4}{\pi^3}.\tag{3}$$
I tried several different ways to compute: $$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^3}{64^n(n+1)}\tag{4}.$$
It seems that is easier than $(1)$ and $(2)$, but it still eludes me.

---

**Updated 1:**
Thanks to Mariusz Iwaniuk and KStarGamer we have (see https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/08/05/01/01/06/0002/):
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}E(\sin({k}))dk=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})^4}{2\pi}+\frac{\pi^3}{8\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})^4} ,$$
where $E(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind. This integral implies:
$${_3F_2(-1/2,1/2,1/2;1,1;1)}=\frac{\pi}{2\Gamma(3/4)^4}+\frac{2\Gamma(3/4)^4}{\pi^3},$$
and Wolfram and Mathematica are unable to deal with it.

---

**Updated 2:**
The natural question is to ask about the closed form of:

$$S'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^3}{64^n(n+1)^ 4}={_5F_4(1/2,1/2,1/2,1,1;2,2,2,2;1)}\tag{5},$$
If we find the closed form of $S'$ also we will get the closed form for:
$$I'=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}k\cot(k)K(\sin(k))dk\\=\frac{3\pi^2\log{2}}{4}+\frac{5\Gamma(3/4)^4}{\pi}+\frac{\pi^3}{4\Gamma(3/4)^4}-\pi G+\frac{\pi^2S'}{64}-\frac{3\pi^2}{4} \tag{6},$$
where $K(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind and G is Catalan's constant.

---

**Updated 3:**
It can be done using $(6)$ also:
$$
I'=\frac{3\pi^2\log{2}}{4}-\frac{\pi^2 S_{2}}{64}-\pi G \tag{7},
$$
where:
$$S_{2}={_5F_4(1,1,3/2,3/2,3/2;2,2,2,2;1)}.$$
As @SetnessRamesory has suggested probably $S'$ and $S_{2}$ don't have easy closed forms. But at least we know from $(6)$ and $(7)$ this nice relation:
$${_5F_4(1/2,1/2,1/2,1,1;2,2,2,2;1)}+{_5F_4(1,1,3/2,3/2,3/2;2,2,2,2;1)}=-\frac{320\Gamma{(3/4)}^4}{\pi^3}-\frac{16\pi}{\Gamma{(3/4)}^4}+48.\tag{8}$$

This question is going to be updated for a while. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Looks like: $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\binom{2 n}{n}^3}{64^n (n+1)}=\frac{\pi }{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4}-\frac{4 \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4}{\pi ^3}$$

Comment: For what it’s worth, the more general series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^3}{64^n(n+1)}z^n$$ is [known](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/08/05/01/01/06/0002/).

Comment: Thanks @KStarGamer this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Please try to choose more descriptive titles in the future. There are a lot of series with binomial coefficients after all.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoB I will improve the titles. Best all.

Comment: Maple does $S'$ in terms of a Meijer G function:
$$ S' = \pi^{-3/2} \text{MeijerG}([[1],[2,2,2,2]],[[1,1,1/2,1/2,1/2],[]],-1)$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael S' is: $$_5F_4(1/2,1/2,1/2,1,1;2,2,2,2;1)$$ maybe Dougall's formula?

Comment: We can do term by term integration of the series https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2151053/72031 and arrive at your series.

Comment: The cases $k=1,2,3$ could be done directly(even WA can solve them). $k=4$ seems not to have an easier expression.

Comment: @SetnessRamesory I've updated the question.